# How many distinct subsets of binary boolean operators are closed under composition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, binary-operations

Question:

> There are $2^4=16$ distinct binary boolean operators. Two operators are regarded the same if one can be obtained from the other by exchanging the operands (input). It is easy to see only $12$ operators remain. How many distinct subsets of the $12$ are closed under composition?

I think the $12$ operators are {$T,F$, Identity, Not, And, Nand, Or, Nor, Implies, Non-implies, Equivalent, Xor (Non-equivalent)} respectively, where $T$ and $F$ are $0$-ary, Identity and Not are unary and the rest are truly binary. It's not hard to apply brute force as the number of cases is sufficiently small ($2^{11}=2048$ cases, since the identity must be included, which is the compositions of $0$ operators). But I would like to see a more elegant argument, one that may provide some insight into why the closed subsets are what they are and why there are no others. Many thanks.

Bonus: It will be much more appreciated if additional interpretations of the restricted range of logic represented by each closed subset are provided.

Comment: Identity and Not are **unary** operators.

Comment: @learner They can be regarded as binary boolean operators which take only the first input. The ones that take the second input are regarded the same. That's why $12$ remain.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "composition" here?

Comment: Why not starting with brute force and then finding an elegant argument for the result? I think it can be done with pencil and paper because the number of closed subsets is much less than $2048$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Any composition is treated as a binary operator by assigning one of two independent boolean values to each of the available operands, e.g. (x And y) Or y

Comment: @mbjoe Yeah! You certainly can get your hands dirty before providing an elegant argument.

Comment: Do you consider, for example $f(P, Q) = P \text{ or } (Q \text{ nand } P)$ as a composition? This is actually a composistion of these operators along with injection of $2^2 \to 2^3$. But without this sort of reduction, most of your compositions are going to trinary operators or greater, and therefore not in your set.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, it's a composition of two operators Or and Nand.

Comment: @YuiTo Cheng you may want to take a look to Post's Lattice (see for example [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.9995&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

Comment: That does not answer the question I asked. The way you've stated this problem, the answer is that NO non-empty subset of the operators is closed under composition. The reason being that all the operators are binary, whereas compositions will always result in trinary or higher operators (even with "T" and "F", which are constant binary operators, not just values). The only way to get a non-trivial answer to your question is to also include composition with some reduction operator from $\{T, F\}^2$ to $\{T, F\}^n$ for some $n$, such as $(P,Q) \mapsto (P,P,Q)$ or $(P,Q) \mapsto (P,P,Q,P)$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Really? I think {Identity, Not} is such an example...

Comment: No. You yourself specified that every operator is *binary*. When you treat those as binary operations, you will see that any composition of them is either trinary or higher.

Comment: @PaulSinclair $(P,P,Q)$ is considered as $2$ inputs (binary) though...

Comment: That is what i've been asking about. That map, $(P, Q) \mapsto (P,P,Q)$, is binary, but is not an operator (which requires it to have codomain $\{T, F\}$). Thus, it is cannot be in your set of binary operators that you want to be closed under composition. This is why I've been trying to get you to clarify your statements. Because the way you have stated this question does not allow you to use that reduction.